# How to solve $x^2y'+xy+x^2y^2=4$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem and I am not able to solve it. I just need a hint what kind of method I should use for this equation. Thank you.

$$x^2y'+xy+x^2y^2=4$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint}$
$$
v = yx\implies y' = \frac{v'}{x} - \frac{v}{x^2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is a ricatti equation. Try substituting $y=Q\frac{w'}{w}$, the picking $Q$ such that the two terms with $\frac{(w')^2}{w^2}$ cancel. (The resulting equation will be linear and homogeneous second order)

Knowing this is useful because when you have an equation of the form

$$Ay'+By^2+Cy+D=0$$

where everything is a function, this substitution always gives you a second order linear homogeneous equation.